# Set value of T when using expression

Tags: c#

I am trying to be able to set a value in a `viewModel` according to what is needed. So let me explain what I'm trying to do before I get to my question.

I would like to have a method in an abstract class that will have a signature like.

`SetValue<FooViewModel>(someClassToSetValueIn, viewModel, (vm)=> vm.Id);`

So I have been looking into this, however, I don't understand why exactly what I'm getting a null value here for the property name.

```
    protected void SetValue<TSource, TResult>(PageableDropDownModel model, TSource viewModel,
        Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> property) where TSource:class
    {
        var viewModelProperty = viewModel.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name); //property.Name is null
        model.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(viewModelProperty?.GetValue(viewModel));
    }
```

Can someone please why `property.Name` is null and how i can get this to work.

Comment: Why do you even want this? It seems like an abstraction that isn't needed.

Comment: Why `Expression<...>` when you could just pass the delegate as-is so you can actually invoke it with `viewModel` as the argument?

Comment: What do you expect the `Name` of a lambda expression to be?

Comment: @DavidG I want to be able to set the value of any property in the viewModel with this method. if there is a better way please tell me as i am open to suggestions. please provide a reason that it is better though.

Comment: Yes, but why not just set the value like you would normally? Why do you need a generic method and expression to do it?

Comment: @3xGuy: I think DavidG wants to say that instead of `SetValue<FooViewModel>(someClassToSetValueIn, viewModel, (vm)=> vm.Id);` you could just write `someClassToSetValueIn.SelectedValue = viewModel.Id;`, which is shorter, does the same thing and does not need a method at all.

Comment: Thank you, I understand what he was asking, however, `SetValue<T>` does a lot more than I showed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you call `property` is not a property, it's an **expression**.

Your expression `(vm) => vm.Id` contains a `MemberExpression` in its body, which, in turn, has a `Member`, which has a `Name`.

Long story short, you can extract the property name as follows:

```
protected void SetValue<TSource, TResult>(..., Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> expression) ...
{
    var propertyName = ((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member.Name;
    ...
}
```

Do note, though, that current versions of C# support `nameof` expressions, i.e., you could simplify your code as follows:

```
protected void SetValue<TSource, TResult>(..., string propertyName) ...
{
    ...
}
```

and call it as

```
SetValue<FooViewModel>(someClassToSetValueIn, viewModel, nameof(vm.Id));
```